# Qjckctl doesn't see soundcard in Connections page

Tags: ubuntu, audio, jack

When I try to setup JACK with Qjckctl, I can go into Setup and find my soundcard:

[image: Setup page of QJackctl]
However, once I start JACK and go onto the Connections page, I can't see my soundcard:

[image: Connections page of QJackctl]
I thought this might be because my soundcard isn't supported, but then how come I can see it in the setup page? I can also find it when I start up alsamixer.

My soundcard is an iCONNEX by iKey-Audio and I have an HP EliteBook running Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

The answer (if I'm not mistaken) is that Qjacktcl (or JACK) did see my soundcard, it just named it system which I didn't expect. I also didn't test my soundcard properly when I posted this question which is why I was confused.